SvelteKit / Problem with CSS-Stylesheets and Event-Calendar Module
I've got stuck on a problem with SvelteKit, CSS and the event-calendar module.
I just open a new skeleton SvelteKit-project to test some of the calendar-modules.
Everything good at this point. But somehow I'm not able to use the installed css-files from the modules.
This is my +page.svelte:
<script>
    import '@event-calendar/core/index.css';
    import Calendar from '@event-calendar/core';
    import TimeGrid from '@event-calendar/day-grid';

    let plugins = [TimeGrid];
    let options = {
        view: 'dayGridMonth', 
        events: []
    };
</script>

<div class="ec-dark">
    <Calendar {plugins}{options} />
</div>


It doesn't matter how I tried to import the css-file or declare the ec-dark-class. My browser is not able to use the stylesheet and I don't now why.
I tried different paths, imported it in a +layout.svelte, make a  with the import, set a :global in the original css-file, tried to import it in the app.html-file in the head-section (like announced in the git-repo to event-calendar)... In the web inspector I can see that the div-class is still there but there are no styles applied on it.

You're not really doing anything wrong, the styling scheme for this component is quite confusing.
In fact, the index.css style definition file located in the @event-calendar/core package will be automatically linked to in the head section of your app.html file by the Vite dev server when you do import Calendar from '@event-calendar/core';, so you don't actually need to explicitly import it or link to it (you might still have to do so when you build for production however).
The way the styles are defined expect you to declare ec-dark as a class on the body, not on the div holding the component, which should be styled as ec. My guess is ec-dark was meant as a global dark vs. light modifier, which is corroborated by the fact that the CSS file defines .ec-dark .ec { ... } which clearly indicates a hierarchy where the ec-styled element is a descendant of the ec-dark-styled element (and the best guarantee to achieve this is to style the body that way since it is the top-most element).
Note that this will not suffice in rendering what you would expect. If you inspect the demo, you will notice that the dark background and lighter text color are not defined inside the module's CSS file, but outside of it, in a separate global.css file. This is the rule in question:
body.ec-dark {
    background: #22272e;
    color: #adbac7;
}

which is something you will have to duplicate in your code to achieve a similar effect.

Ah ok, I see. I just tried also to add the ec-dark-class to the body but nothing happend - or maybe I really expect some bigger changes..
I will try some thinks.
Thank you :)
